# Heroku Error when Installing

Tags: software-installation, updates, heroku

I'm trying to download Heroku for the first time onto my Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm following the Heroku website's instructions exactly by the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./"
curl -L https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install heroku
```

But every time I get to sudo apt-get update I receive the following errors:

```
W: the repository 'http:''cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt/./Packages
403 Forbidden [IP: 52.84.3.182 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignore, or old ones used instead.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./Release
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Also, when I do heroku -v it says it is not installed. Yet, when I do a sudo apt-get update the page is filled with cli-heroku links

Comment: Are you using an HTTP proxy or a weird DNS server? What's the output of `host cli-assets.heroku.com` vs. `host cli-assets.heroku.com 8.8.8.8`? What happens when you try to access http://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt/./Packages with your web browser or a command-line HTTP client like `wget` or `curl`?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried on Ubuntu 16.10 and it works.

Try running the commands line by line and not do a copy and paste of the full thing. make sure that there are no funny characters added at the beginning and end (like $ and ~) so that the phrase is exactly the same as you see it. Sometimes when copying and pasting from the web extra characters get added. To paste on the command line use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Do you get any message in return?

After running the first line, run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep heroku` to see if the new heroku repository is there. If it is not, then the first line did not work. You should see something like this:

> `deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./`
>
> `# deb-src https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./`

The second line should add the key to authenticate, so you should not be getting the error saying that the data cannot be authenticated. To verify that it is added after you run it, type `sudo apt-key list | grep heroku`. You should get something like this:

> `uid           [ unknown] Heroku Release Engineering <release@heroku.com>`

Then do the update and install and you are good to go :)